# Imprimir Cards con v-for - Vue.js

Tags: bootstrap, vue.js

estoy extrayendo información desde axios y la estoy imprimiendo desde mi v-for  e imprimir mis cards pero lo hace de una forma que no entiendo porque.

Ahorita así tengo mis cards. la información Ya la Extrae.

se supone que debo de imprimir así [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando le agrego a mi a mid Div el `v-for="lista in listaPro`
me lo imprime de esta manera

```html
<div class="col-9 ">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" id="listaproyectos">
      <div class="card text-align textocorrecto" v-for="lista in listaPro">
        <!--Card image-->
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" alt="Card image cap">

        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-body">
          <!--Title-->
          <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
          <!--Text-->
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

tambien he puesto en otro div el `v-for="lista in listaPro` Pero desconozco porque pasa eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el HTML que te ha generado por favor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, solo lo puse asi

```
<div class="row" id="listaproyectos" >
   <div class="col-4" v-for="lista in listaPro"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Podrias aceptar la respuesta?